# Detect if combobox has been modified in the last Xs

Tags: vba, ms-access, time, combobox

I am struggling with a combobox query.
The scrolldown it generates is quite long and I want the combobox to be in a "Search as you type" fashion. However each search is super slow and runs each time a single letter is added. Even if I type "abc" super fast, the query will run on "a", then "ab" and finally "abc", spending a huge time for nothing.

To counter that, I would like to be able to detect when the combobox has been left unchanged for 1s for example before launching my query, to allow a user typing relatively fast to avoid having his query launched too many times.

My current code is as follow:

```
Public Sub FilterComboAsYouType(combo As ComboBox, defaultSQL As String, lookupField As String)
Dim strSQL As String
    If Len(combo.Text) > 1 Then
        
        strSQL = defaultSQL & " WHERE " & lookupField
        combo.RowSource = strSQL
        combo.Dropdown
    End If


End Sub


Private Sub combo42_Change()
    FilterComboAsYouType Me.Combo42, "SQL here", "Parameters here"
```

Comment: Your `FilterComboAsYouType` goes into `DoSearch()`.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-32.html